# MojoExecutionException Maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm running my Java application using Mavin and after the running, I have this message:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project test: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 16 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Could you help me please

Comment: Not using JDK16 for building... set your environment variable JAVA_HOME accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem:

- Eclipse 2021-06
- maven-compiler-plugin v3.8.1
  -> "invalid target release: 16"

Changing the default JRE under "Preferences/Installed JREs" from 14 to 16 fixed this for me. (The Build was set correctly to JDK 16 all along, so Maven should have been using the 16 Runtime Environment which was pointed at JDK 16, but it obviously wasn't)

Answer (score -1):

Go to java build path and set JAVA_HOME to jdk not to JDK_DIR/jre

Comment: If you JAVA_HOME is not set to JDK it would produce a different error message.

Comment: How can I acces to java build path and set JAVA_HOMR to jdk?